# =+ operator in Arduino

Tags: arduino

Can anybody tell me what this operation in the Arduino language is doing?

```
magbias = +470.;
```

It is not the same as `magbias += 470`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anybody can tell me what is this operation doing?

The `+` is the unary plus operator, and it is effectively a no-op.

```
magbias = +470;
```

is equivalent to

```
magbias = 470;
```

> It is not the same as magbias += 470, right?

Correct.

---

Normally, I would say "read the language reference", but in this case, the reference document doesn't describe the unary `+` or unary `-` operators.  They are just listed in the operator precedence table.

Comment: "It is effectively a no-op" in this case because immediates are assumed to be positive. Hell, the compiler would remove it altogether.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the same, but I believed that it was too obviuos and a little absurd.

Answer (score 0):

magbias +=470 means magbias = magbias + 470; i.e. its adds in 470 to the previous value and stores it in the same variable.
magbias = +470; is defining value to the variable.